# cómo convertir un float a int en el usando el flask

Tags: python, flask

Hola estoy tratando de convertir un valor tipo float a int dentro del template usando flask

```
{{productos.cantidad}}
```

aqui esta el valor que estoy imprimiendo en el template y trate de usar

```
{{int(productos.cantidad)}}
```

y no jala espero su apoyo

Comment: y por que no mejor convertirlos antes de que lleguen a la vista, te dejo un recurso de interés http://theartofpythonprogramming.blogspot.mx/2012/03/conversion-de-tipo-de-datos.html

Comment: si pense en hacer eso pero queria saber si existe otra forma que ya tenga incorporado flask para no tener que meter un for ya que es una lista de datos lo que estoy buscando

Answer (score 0):

Flask usa [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) como lenguaje para los templates. En la documentación de Jinja puedes ver que la forma de convertir variables del template usa su propia sintaxis, que llama [filtros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#filters), y tiene [una serie de ellos](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#builtin-filters) predefinidos.

En tu caso sería:

```
{{productos.cantidad|int}}
```

Comment: gracias si me jalo

Comment: @EmmanuelCapistran De nada. Puedes leerte [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) y [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para aprender a usar mejor stackoverflow

Comment: muchas gracias aun soy muy nuevo en esta plataforma